# Query Firestore field/value using multiple multiple 'where' values?

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore

I'm considering letting users follow other users in a app, and would have a feed of posts from people who they follow.

Is there a way to query multiple 'where' statements at once, or compare to a List? Or would a alternate route need to be taken?

Here is a example scenario in NodeJS:

```
var usersFollowed = ['GKXgK2CPPGPQjmQ3Lsrh', 'cBjzo3MSjjaOHksVmO0o', 'tc9gMwZR9SiyjWonyCWF'];

var followingPosts = await db.collection('posts').where('posterUID', '==', usersFollowed.Any()).get();
```

(`.Any()` is made up and what I would like to do)

Here is a example of a post's document in Firestore:

```
postID
    caption: 'a picture of something'
    type: 'picutre'
    size: 1
    posterUID: GKXgK2CPPGPQjmQ3Lsrh
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use the [`in`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/queries#in_not-in_and_array-contains-any) operator: "Use the `in` operator to combine up to 10 equality (==) clauses on the same field with a logical OR. An `in` query returns documents where the given field matches any of the comparison values".

```
var usersFollowed = ['GKXgK2CPPGPQjmQ3Lsrh', 'cBjzo3MSjjaOHksVmO0o', 'tc9gMwZR9SiyjWonyCWF'];
var followingPosts = await db.collection('posts').where('posterUID', 'in', usersFollowed).get();
```

However, note that you **can only combine up to 10 equality (==) clauses**.

If you need to combine more than 10 clauses, you will need to do several similar queries and merge the results. This [article](https://medium.com/firebase-tips-tricks/how-to-combined-two-firestore-queries-to-simulate-a-logical-or-query-27d28a43cb2d) explains how to merge two queries with the JS SDK.

Comment: This wouldn't work as the `posterUID` is a string. I'm updating the question to reflect this, thanks anyways.

Comment: Sorry, my mistake... it should be the `in` operator.  I'm going to re-write the answer.